# Constructing a linear grammar for the language

Tags: grammar, context-free-grammar, lexical-analysis, formal-languages, context-free-language

I find difficulties in constructing a Grammar for the language especially with linear grammar.

Can anyone please give me some basic tips/methodology where i can construct the grammar for any language ? thanks in advance

I have a doubt whether the answer for this question "Construct a linear grammar for the language: is right

L ={a^n b c^n | n belongs to Natural numbers}

Solution:

Right-Linear Grammar :

S--> aS | bA

A--> cA | ^

Left-Linear Grammar:

S--> Sc | Ab

A--> Aa | ^

Comment: Can you clearly define "linear grammar"?

Comment: @Welbog: A linear grammar is a context free grammar that has at most one non-terminal on the right-hand side of any production. ([wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_grammar))

Comment: @ejaz: This language does not have either a right-linear or a left-linear grammar, because it is not a regular language. However, the obvious grammar for the language is linear (with the non-terminal in the middle). (The grammars you present don't work because nothing in them restricts the count of a's and c's to be the same.)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a programming question.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the comments, these grammars are wrong since they generate strings not in the language. Here's a derivation of `abcc` in both grammars:

```
S -> aS -> abA -> abcA -> abccA -> abcc
S -> Sc -> Scc -> Abcc -> Aabcc -> abcc
```

Also as pointed out in the comments, there is a simple linear grammar for this language, where a linear grammar is defined as having at most one nonterminal symbol in the RHS of any production:

```
S -> aSc | b
```

There are some general rules for constructing grammars for languages. These are either obvious simple rules or rules derived from closure properties and the way grammars work. For instance:

1. if `L = {a}` for an alphabet symbol `a`, then `S -> a` is a gammar for `L`.
2. if `L = {e}` for the empty string `e`, then `S -> e` is a grammar for `L`.
3. if `L = R U T` for languages `R` and `T`, then `S -> S' | S''` along with the grammars for `R` and `T` are a grammar for `L` if `S'` is the start symbol of the grammar for `R` and `S''` is the start symbol of the grammar for `T`.
4. if `L = RT` for languages `R` and `T`, then `S = S'S''` is a grammar for `L` if `S'` is the start symbol of the grammar for `R` and `S''` is the start symbol of the grammar for `T`.
5. if `L = R*` for language `R`, then `S = S'S | e` is a grammar for `L` if `S'` is the start symbol of the grammar for `R`.

Rules 4 and 5, as written, do not preserve linearity. Linearity can be preserved for left-linear and right-linear grammars (since those grammars describe regular languages, and regular languages are closed under these kinds of operations); but linearity cannot be preserved in general. To prove this, an example suffices:

```
R -> aRb | ab
T -> cTd | cd

L  = RT = a^n b^n c^m d^m, 0 < a,b,c,d
L' = R* = (a^n b^n)*, 0 < a,b
```

Suppose there were a linear grammar for `L`. We must have a production for the start symbol `S` that produces something. To produce something, we require a string of terminal and nonterminal symbols. To be linear, we must have at most one nonterminal symbol. That is, our production must be of the form

```
S := xYz
```

where x is a string of terminals, Y is a single nonterminal, and z is a string of terminals. If `x` is non-empty, reflection shows the only useful choice is `a`; anything else fails to derive known strings in the language. Similarly, if `z` is non-empty, the only useful choice is `d`. This gives four cases:

1. `x` empty, `z` empty. This is useless, since we now have the same problem to solve for nonterminal `Y` as we had for `S`.
2. `x = a`, `z` empty. `Y` must now generate exactly `a^n' b^n' b c^m d^m` where `n' = n - 1`. But then the exact same argument applies to the grammar whose start symbol is `Y`.
3. `x` empty, `z = d`. `Y` must now generate exactly `a^n b^n c c^m' d^m'` where `m' = m - 1`. But then the exact same argument applies to the grammar whose start symbol is `Y`.
4. `x = a`, `z = d`. `Y` must now generate exactly `a^n' b^n' bc c^m' d^m'` where `n'` and `m'` are as in 2 and 3. But then the exact same argument applies to the grammar whose start symbol is `Y`.

None of the possible choices for a useful production for `S` is actually useful in getting us closer to a string in the language. Therefore, no strings are derived, a contradiction, meaning that the grammar for `L` cannot be linear.

Suppose there were a grammar for `L'`. Then that grammar has to generate all the strings in `(a^n b^n)R(a^m b^m)`, plus those in `e + R`. But it can't generate the ones in the former by the argument used above: any production useful for that purpose would get us no closer to a string in the language.